# show that $|\langle b,v\rangle|\leq \frac{1}{2\alpha}\|b\|^2 +\frac{\alpha}{2}\|v\|^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let H be hilbert space  $A:H\to H$ and $J:H\to \mathbb R$
$A$ symetric $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle x,Ax\rangle$ and coercive $\exists \alpha >0$ such that $\langle Ax,x\rangle\ge \alpha \|x\|$
let $b\in H$ s.t we have $J(v)=\frac 12 \langle Ax,x\rangle -\langle b,v\rangle$
Show that $J$ is continuous and show that $|\langle b,v\rangle|\leq \frac{1}{2\alpha}\|b\|^2 +\frac{\alpha}{2}\|v\|^2$.
I proved that $J$ is bounded from below so continuous ? and I dont know how to prove the second question.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4129910/42969 (it is for Hilbert spaces over the field of complex numbers. For real numbers it is even simpler).

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much I got it now

Comment: @MartinR about continyuty is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is not that hard. First observe
$$
\frac{1}{2\alpha}\lVert b \rVert^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\lVert v \rVert^2 = \frac{1}{2\alpha}\left( \lVert b \rVert^2 + \alpha^2\lVert v \rVert^2\right) = \frac{1}{2\alpha} \left( \underbrace{\left( \lVert b \rVert - \alpha\lVert v \rVert\right)^2}_{\geq 0} +2\alpha \lVert b \rVert \lVert v \rVert \right) \geq \frac{1}{2\alpha} \left( 2\alpha \lVert b \rVert \lVert v \rVert\right)
$$
Then use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\lVert b \rVert \lVert v \rVert \geq \lvert \langle b, v \rangle \rvert
$$
This proves your inequality. So it is a very elementary one. This is also known as Young's inequality.